# Brownian motion on the circle and Itô processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider the differential system
\begin{cases}
dX_t &=& -\frac{1}{2}X_t dt - Y_tdB_t,  \\
dY_t &=& -\frac{1}{2}Y_tdt + X_tdB_t,
\end{cases}

$X_0 = 1$, $Y_0 = 0$.

Let $X_t$ and $Y_t$ be a solution of the given system. For $m \in \mathbb{N}$, let us define the sequence of stopping time
\begin{gather*}
\tau_m = 
\begin{cases}
\inf\{t \geq 0: X_t + Y_t \geq m\}, &\text{if}& \{t \geq 0: X_t + Y_t \geq m\} \neq \emptyset, \\
+\infty &\text{otherwise}&.
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}
How to prove that $X_{t \wedge \tau_m}$ and $Y_{t\wedge \tau_m}$ are Itô processes ? (In my definition, we say that $X_t$ is an Itô process if $X_t = M_t + V_t$, where $(M_t)$ is a continuous martingale in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and $(V_t)$ is supposed to be continuous, of bounded variation, adapted and equal to $0$ at $t=0$).

Thank you. Marcus

Comment: Not any help here?

Comment: The question is odd since $\tau_1=0$ and $\tau_m=+\infty$ for every $m\geqslant2$. Hint: the SDE system is solved by $$(X_t,Y_t)=(\cos B_t,\sin B_t).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $(X_t,Y_t)_t$ is a solution to the given system. Then in particular, we can write

$$X_t-X_0 = - \underbrace{\int_0^t Y_s \, dB_s}_{\text{local martingale}} - \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\int_0^t X_s \, ds}_{\text{bounded variation, continuous}}.$$

Applying the optional stopping theorem yields that

$$(t,\omega) \mapsto \left( \int_0^{t \wedge \tau} Y_s \, dB_s \right)(\omega)$$

is a martingale for any stopping time $\tau$. Hence,

$$X_{t \wedge \tau}-X_0 = - \underbrace{\int_0^{t \wedge \tau} Y_s \, dB_s}_{\text{local martingale}} - \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\int_0^{t \wedge \tau} X_s \, ds}_{\text{bounded variation, continuous}}.$$

Finally, note the "local martingale"-part is a martingale if

$$\sup_{s \in [0,\tau]} |Y_s| \leq c < \infty$$

for some constant $c$ which does not depend on $\omega$. Obviously, this assumption is satisfied for $\tau_m$ (see OP for the definition).

Clearly, the same argumentation applies to $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$.

Comment: Okay thank you. I have totally forgotten the optional stopping time theorem. But now, in the beginning, how can you say that they are martingales and function of bounded variation respectively? I know that a (strong) solution to the a SDE has the following properties: $(X_t)$ is adapted, both integrals in the first equation are well-defined and $(X_t)$ satisfies the first equation. But I think that the first integral is a martingale if $E(\int_0^t X_t^2 ds) < +\infty$. Why would it be?

Comment: @MCrassus How do you define that a stochastic integral of the form $$\int_0^t f(s) \, dB_s$$ is well-defined? What kind of assumptions do you use? (I'm just asking because there are several ones.)

Comment: @MCrassus I have rewritten my answer; hopefully, it's clear now.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay.. I was working in a company yesterday. So thank you very much for your precise answer! To answer your question of understanding, tell me if I am wrong but I think the best we have is that the integral is well-defined if $(f(s))$ is adapted and $\int_0^t f(s)ds < \infty$ almost surely. So it implies that if a process $H$ is adapted and continuous, then the integral $\int_0^t H_s dB_s$ is well-defined. But with this weak assumption, we lost the martingale property of the integral..

Comment: So one sufficient condition for this integral to be a martingale is $E(\int_0^t (f(s))^2 ds) < \infty$. But we also know that the integrals defined with the weakest conditions above, are local martingales with probability $1$.